# Azure AD and Core Idenity Roles Hybrid

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1, claims-based-identity

Is it possible to use Azure AD and Core Identity Roles together? Basically the user will log into the App using AD, which I have that done already. But as they use the app, thier roles will be based on the AspNetRoles and AspNetUsersRoles tables. I was thinking that I would have to use the ClaimsPrincipal factory to extend the claims object that is created when the user logs in.

Comment: Hi @Jack Thor. Did you implement your idea or decided to go with AppRoles finally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the ASP.NET identity you can manage the user locally in your database, and user Azure AD as external identity provider which enable the AAD accounts to login in your application. You can identify the user and link it to the user in your local database. You can then also manage the roles with your local users and Azure AD users.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

- Create a new application with Individual User Accounts.
- Install this package : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI
- `services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(`
- `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); services.AddDefaultIdentity() .AddEntityFrameworkStores();`
  `services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => }).AddAzureAD(options =>`
  `Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options)).AddCookie();`
- Update  `appsettings.json "AzureAd": { "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",`
- `"Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com", "TenantId": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-4f08-b544-b1eb456f228d",`
- `"ClientId": "xxxxx-xxxxx-4717-9821-e4f718fbece4", "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",`
- `"CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External" },`

It depends on the user to choose login with local authentication or Azure [AD Authentication.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims)