# Use Azure AD authentication but manage roles in database in .NET 6

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

#### Scenario

I have a platform with multiple smaller applications. Each application needs its own roles, and users may have multiple roles since they might need to access different applications on the platform.

#### Problem

I have a .NET 6 web API that currently uses application roles on Azure to deal with authorization. It gets very messy since I have to manage multiple Azure groups for each application, e.g., "App 1 Admins", "App 1 Users", "App 2 Admins", "App 2 Users", etc. I want to move the authorization part to the database instead (using something like AspNetRoles). This way, I wouldn't have to create a new group on AD for each role and application and add users to it. Instead, I have a "user management" page where roles are assigned on my own platform.

Currently, I have a working way of adding Azure users and their information to the database using `OnTokenValidated`. I also created my own `Roles` table, as well as `UserRoles` table that maps Azure users in the DB to roles. How can I utilize these roles with the `[Authorize(Roles = "App1.Admin, App1.User"]` attribute instead of the Azure AD ones? I first thought I could add claims to the user in `OnTokenValidated`, but then I came across a few resources on this, for example:

[Azure AD and Core Idenity Roles Hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717516/azure-ad-and-core-idenity-roles-hybrid)

[Azure AD authentication to existing ASP.NET Core Identity application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73227205/azure-ad-authentication-to-existing-asp-net-core-identity-application)

[Log in with Azure AD and get a UserManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421775/log-in-with-azure-ad-and-get-a-usermanager)

I use Microsoft Identity like so:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

I tried following [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66697024/10338762). I made the changes to generate the `AspNet` tables and added DI, etc. However, my app is still authorizing from Azure AD. Someone also mentioned that an AspNetUser can automatically be created with `"CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"` in my appsettings.json under "AzureAd", but nothing gets created.

What is the best move here? I think one option could be to create a custom Authorize attribute that checks the database for the user's roles as well. Is there anything I can do to utilize the normal `[Authorize]` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend the approach in this [link you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421775/log-in-with-azure-ad-and-get-a-usermanager). It has all the infrastructure needed to accomplish the goal of authorizing using a [role-based policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0).
As long as each application can reach the database where the Identity tables are defined.

The RoleManager ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0)) handle all the services for you i.e. creation, deletion etc.

You can then also use the UserManager ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.isinroleasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanager-1-isinroleasync(-0-system-string))) to check whether the User has a Role against the Roles database: UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, string role); If you want to eventually add more complex logic in a custom Authorization triad (Requirement-Handler-Policy)

Also, I can highly recommend [this youtube series](https://%20https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOeFnOV9YBa4yaz-uIi5T4ZW3QQGHJQXi) on Authentication and Authorization in .NET COre. It dives deep into the topic including Custom, Role-based, Claim-based Authorization, etc.